# How do you merge older data with an apend only stream database?

Tags: nosql

I've been reading about streaming databases that record all events as immutable entries in an append-only log. Then map/reduce jobs or something like a "materialized view" is constructed reading the logs to get the current state.

However, my question is about interfacing with external systems that must be pulled from. How are you supposed to add their data to the append-only database in a way that prevent duplicates and orders the data correctly?

Consider a nightly cron to pull XYZ and insert it into the stream of todays data.

Comment: More information required. What is your main database? What is your `cron` job copying/inserting?

Comment: I don't have a streaming, distributed database or cron job. I was just just giving an example as I'm not sure how to merge the concepts of continuous series elements with a mutable data source. This is kind of a partition-merge issue in a way except unlike CAP theorem, the two systems aren't starting from the same place as a way to resolve conflicts.